# How to group results by count of relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given tables, `Profiles`, and `Memberships` where a profile has many memberships, how do I query profiles based on the number of memberships?

For example I want to get the number of profiles with 2 memberships. I can get the number of profiles for each membership with:

```
SELECT "memberships"."profile_id", COUNT("profiles"."id") AS "membership_count"
FROM "profiles"
INNER JOIN "memberships" on "profiles"."id" = "memberships"."profile_id"
GROUP BY "memberships"."profile_id"
```

That returns results like

```
profile_id | membership_count
_____________________________
1            2
2            5
3            2
...
```

But how do I group and sum the counts to get the query to return results like:

```
n | profiles_with_n_memberships
_____________________________
1   36
2   28
3   29
...
```

Or even just a query for a single value of `n` that would return

```
profiles_with_2_memberships
___________________________
28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your sample data, but I just recreated the scenario here with a single table : [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad713/6)

You could `LEFT JOIN` the counts with `generate_series()`  and get zeroes for missing count of `n` memberships. If you don't want zeros, just use the second query.

*Query1*

```
WITH c
AS (
    SELECT profile_id
        ,count(*) ct
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY profile_id
    )
    ,m
AS (
    SELECT MAX(ct) AS max_ct
    FROM c
    )
SELECT n
    ,COUNT(c.profile_id)
FROM m
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, m.max_ct) AS i(n)
LEFT JOIN c ON c.ct = i.n
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY n;
```

*Query2*

```
WITH c
AS (
    SELECT profile_id
        ,count(*) ct
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY profile_id
    )
SELECT ct
      ,COUNT(*)
 FROM c 
GROUP BY ct
ORDER BY ct;
```