# Counting Frequencies for Orders by Customers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an Orders table with the following (simplified) columns:

1. id (integer)
2. user_id (integer)
3. status (integer for enum)

I'm trying to create a frequency distribution chart.

**Q: How do I translate the schema above to get the following columns?**

1. number of orders
2. number of users

And example result would be:

```
| number of orders | number of users |
|------------------|-----------------|
| 0                | 2000            |
| 1                | 25              |
| 2                | 3               |
| 3                | 2               |
| 4                | 1               |
```

Of course, if someone places "5" orders, I'd want the "Number of orders" column to increase accordingly in the future.

So far, I've only been able to count Users that have placed more than one order:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Repeat Customers"
FROM (
    SELECT  o.user_id
    FROM    Orders o
    WHERE  o.status >= 4
    GROUP   BY o.user_id
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT o.user_id) = 1 AND COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY o.user_id
```

**Update:** Sorry about this, guys. I seem to have made an error. Since we're only looking at the Orders table, we can't calculate the number of users with 0 orders, since the logical way to do that would be `all_user_ids - user_ids_in_orders_table`

The right answer schema would be:

```
| number of orders | number of users |
|------------------|-----------------|
| 1                | 25              |
| 2                | 3               |
| 3                | 2               |
| 4                | 1               |
```

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677383/how-to-group-results-by-count-of-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this SQL can help you:

```
SELECT 
    nOrders AS "number of orders",
    COUNT(nUsers) AS "number of users"
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(o.id) AS nOrders, o.user_id AS nUsers
    FROM
        Orders o
    WHERE
        o.status >= 4
    GROUP BY o.user_id) AS a
GROUP BY nOrders
```

Comment: Fails to include users with no orders.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it was the first one, it's easier to understand, and allowed me to easily edit the `WHERE` clause to completely fit my use-case. This is also the only answer where the results are correct.

Comment: @amingilani . . . You can accept whatever answer you like.  However, this does not correctly answer your question because it does not include the row 0/2000.  It seems a bit silly to accept an incorrect answer, but like I said, you can do that because you are the OP.

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff. I just updated the question description. Thing is, the number of users with zero orders would be `all_user_ids - user_ids_in_orders_table `, but since we're not looking at the user's table at all, it's impossible to count them.

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL and thus won't run on Postgres. Identifiers (and a column alias **is** an identifier) can not be specified with single quotes. `'number of orders'` has to be `"number of orders"`

Comment: @amingilani . . . Changing the question like that is pretty rude to other people who tried to help you.

Comment: I'm really sorry changing the question Gordon, but like I said, it isn't logically possible to list the number of users that have 0 orders, if all you have is the order's table. Since there won't be any of those users' ids in the `user_id` column.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

If you want to get a count of 0, then use conditional aggregation:

```
select orders_per_user, count(*)
from (select user_id, sum( (status >= 4)::int ) as orders_per_user 
      from orders 
      group by user_id
     ) o
group by orders_per_user
order by orders_per_user
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit @YvetteColomb. Before you jump in and make edits, ensure that you've read the question and edit. The edit did not invalidate this answer, because in no world can you count the `0th` column with just the users table, meaning this answer cannot be accurate.

Comment: @amingilani that's fine. I'll leave it between you and the answerer here. There was a flag on this post, which is why I came here in the first place.

Comment: "with just the orders* table"

Comment: I understand, thank you for your moderation @YvetteColomb